# Getting information from different lists (SQL Style)

Tags: list, workflow, sql

Is it possible to do something like an SQL query within SP Designer workflows?

e.g I want to do something like "SELECT * FROM list-a WHERE client-id = current-clients-id".

or can someone suggest a different way of approaching the problem

Help much appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot run SQL queries within a SharePoint Designer Workflow.
But it can be possible when you create an Externel List of the SQL table and use that list within your SPD workflow. This can be done using BCS, external content types and an external list.

Comment: is is possible to do something like that? i'm looking for something like the 'WHERE' feature really